# Define a function to be used in multiple classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, copy

Is it possible to define a function that can be used as part of multiple classes?

I first tried this:

```
class solvers:
   def Euler(self):
      self.N += self.dNdt(N) * self.dt

class blob:
   # contents of blob go here

methods = solvers()
blob1 = blob()
blob1.solver = methods.Euler
```

But this only crates aliases to call **Euler** from within **methods**, leaving **blob1.N** unchanged.
I also tried

```
from copy import deepcopy

blob1.solver = deepcopy(methods.Euler)
```

but this approach didn't seem to change **N** in either **methods** or **blob1**.

Comment: You're assigning a bound method. Assign the unbound method: `blob1.solver = solvers.solver`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the solver as an argument to the blob object? I would structure the code as a `Solver` class that contains general methods of all the solvers you want to implement, and then the `Euler` can inherit from that class. Finally you can make an instance of the desired solver and pass that to your blob class like this:

```
class Solver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.N = 0
    # Add other generic solver methods here

class Euler(Solver): # Note that we inherit from Solver
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()  # Tells python to add all generic solver methods to this

    def Euler(self):
        self.N += self.dNdt(N) * self.dt

class blob:
    def __init__(self, solver):
        self.solver = solver

    def blah():
        self.solver.N = 0 # We can access N like this

    # contents of blob go here

blob1 = blob(solver=Euler())
blob1.solver.N = 0  # We can access N like this
```

Now you can access `self.solver.N` from within `blob`.

Unless you are saying that you intend for `self.N` to be shared between instances? That doesn't seem correct to share integration step variables like that though.

**EDIT**

We can pass the parameter of our blob instance to the init function of our solvers to share the information between them, which based on your comment seems to be what you are aiming to do

```
import abc
from abc import ABC

class Solver(ABC):  # Inheriting from ABC means this is just a template class
    def __init__(self, some_n):
        self.N = some_n  # Every Solver instance will be provided with an N variable at initialization
        self.dt = .01  # Every Solver can use this as a time step

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def iteration_step(self):
        pass

class Euler(Solver): # Note that we inherit from Solver
    def __init__(self, some_n): # The Euler solver will take the N argument, solely to pass to the initialization on the next line
        super().__init__(some_n)  # Now the Euler has a self.N property, as well as all other Solver methods

    def iteration_step(self):
        self.N += self.dNdt() * self.dt  # I don't think N needs to be supplied to self.DnDt() because that method can use self.N
        print(self.N)

    def dNdt(self):
        return self.N * 0.05

class blob:
    def __init__(self, solver_class: Solver, n_of_blob):
        self.solver = solver_class(n_of_blob)  # initialize the solver class

    def run(self):
        for x in range(100):
            self.solver.iteration_step()

blob1 = blob(solver_class=Euler, n_of_blob=1.0)  # Note that we remove parenthesis from Euler() so that we can make the instance of solver in blob.__init__()
blob1.run()
print("-" * 80)
for x in range(100):
    blob1.solver.iteration_step()
```

Notice if you run this example you see in the output a line like

```
1.051257959948049
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.051783588928023
```

which is the transition from using the `blob1.run()` method to using the `blob1.solver.iteration_step()` approach showing that the variable is accessible in both scopes

Comment: The issue is that **N** is a property of **blob** that needs to be accessed by other functions that are part of **blob** (and which I want to define using the same methodology as **solver**).  Now I recognize that I could pass **blob.N** to the functions that need it, but that's not as clean as what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found that meets what I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
def Euler(self):
   self.N += self.dNdt(N) * self.dt

class blob:
   def euler(self):
      Euler(self)
```

This allows for opperations such as

```
blob.euler()

blob.solve = blob.euler

blob.solve()
```